# Terminal doesn't recognize nvidia installation

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, graphics

I attempted to install nvidia driver but for some reason, I am not able to get it installed.

```
soon@soon:~$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-525 is already the newest version (525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Secure boot is disabled.

Comment: Based on the output you have the latest version for your system installed, at least that is what the line `nvidia-driver-525 is already the newest version (525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).` is saying.
However, Ubuntu 22.04.1 is not the latest point release of Ubuntu.

Comment: it is resolved, there was a problem with graphics card's power cord.

Comment: @knowsnotmuch Feel free to write that up as an answer to help others that might have had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question!
There was a lose connection to the graphics card. Needed to adjust the power input cable for it to show up.